# After thinking for quite a bit, I haven't been able to completely solve this induction question.

Tags: induction

Can L tilings be created for L shaped structure (such that the L tilings are in fact trominoes). It seems to not be such a simple question to answer! Though their may be multiple ways of answering the same.

Comment: Have you succeeded to find such a tiling for $n=3,5$?

Comment: The title of this question could be improved by making it more specific to the content question.

Comment: I guess we should include other kinds of bigger tiles (typically certain rectangles, e.g. $2\times 3$, or more general L kinds of shapes) in the induction hypothesis.

Comment: @Berci, yes in fact this is possible for all n>=1, which is what we have to prove. You can find such tillings relatively easily for n =3,5 ,etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For the case when $n$ is odd**

It is easy to divide any $3\times 2k$ rectangle into tiles.

So, divide your large L-shape into the following shapes. A and C form a border of width $3$ along the longest sides of the large L-shape.

A. Two $3\times (2n-6)$ rectangle3

B. Two $3\times (n-3)$ rectangles

C. A new L-shape with $n$ replaced by $3$

D. A new large L-shape with $n$ replaced by $n-3$.

You can now apply induction.